# How to debug org-caldav-sync?

Tags: debugging, calendar

I'm trying to sync Google Calendar over OAuth2 using [org-caldav](https://github.com/dengste/org-caldav). However, when I execute `M-x org-caldav-sync`, the following error occurs:

**Messages**:

```
Contacting host: www.googleapis.com:443
json-read: End of file while parsing JSON
```

I can't seem to figure out which process is parsing JSON. Even when I set `org-caldav-debug-level` to `2`, the debug buffer only displays a syncing message:

**org-caldev-debug-buffer**:

```
========== Started sync
```

The only thing which has happened is the creation of an empty appointments.org file.

Is there a way to solve this, or debug what is going wrong?

This my init config (I've added the OAuth providers after reading [this closed ticket](https://github.com/dengste/org-caldav/issues/171)):

```lisp
(use-package org-caldav
  :config
  (setq org-caldav-oauth2-providers
        '((google
           "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
           "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
           "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"
           "https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/%s/events"))
        org-caldav-url 'google
        org-caldav-oauth2-client-id "xxx"
        org-caldav-oauth2-client-secret "xxx"
        org-caldav-calendar-id "xxx"
        org-caldav-inbox "~/org/calendar/appointments.org"
        org-caldav-files '("~/org/calendar/org-caldav.org")))
```